# Network.requestWillBeSent doesn't account for Javascript setTimeout redirections

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer in my Node JS app to get the URLs in a redirect chain, e.g: going from one URL to the next. Up until this point I've been creating ngrok URLs which use simple PHP header functions to redirect a user with 301 and 302 requests, and my starting URL is a page that redirects to one of the ngrok URL's after a few seconds.

However, it appears that `Network.requestWillBeSent` exits if it comes across a page that uses a Javascript redirection, and I need it to somehow wait and pick up these ones as well.

Example journey of URLs:

1. START -> https://example.com/ <-- `setTimeout` and redirects to an ngrok
2. ngrok url uses PHP to redirect with a 301
3. some other ngrok that uses a JS `setTimeout` to redirect to, for example, another https://example.com/
4. FINISH -> https://example.com/

In this situation, `Network.requestWillBeSent` picks up 1 and 2, but finishes on 3 and thus doesn't get to 4.

So rather than it console logging all four URLs, I only get two.

It's difficult to create a reproduction since I can't set up all ngrok urls etc, but here's a [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-fire-qmp0w) and a [Github](https://github.com/sts-ryan-holton/puppeteer-demo) link, attached below is my code:

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const AdvancedFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat');
dayjs.extend(AdvancedFormat);

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function runEmulation () {

  const goToUrl = 'https://example.com/';

  // vars
  const journey = [];
  let hopDataToReturn;

  // initiate a Puppeteer instance with options and launch
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });

  // launch a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // initiate a new CDP session
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await client.send('Network.enable');
  await client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', async (e) => {

    // if not a document, skip
    if (e.type !== 'Document') return;

    console.log(`adding URL to journey: ${e.documentURL}`)

    // the journey
    journey.push({
      url: e.documentURL,
      type: e.redirectResponse ? e.redirectResponse.status : 'JS Redirection',
      duration_in_ms: 0,
      duration_in_sec: 0,
      loaded_at: dayjs().valueOf()
    });
  });

  await page.goto(goToUrl);
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await browser.close();

  console.log('=== JOURNEY ===')
  console.log(journey)
}

// init
runEmulation()
```

What am I missing inside `Network.requestWillBeSent` or what do I need to add in order to pick up websites in the middle that use JS to redirect to another site after a few seconds.

Comment: The callback method of `Network.requestWillBeSent` will run in a different execution context, you cannot add await on it directly. You need to return a Promise to be able to use await

Comment: Are you able to provide an example please? @AmirSaleem

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Since, `client.on("Network.requestWillBeSent")` takes a callback function, you cannot use `await` on this. `await` is only valid for methods that return a Promise. Every `async` function returns a Promise.

As you need to wait for the callback function to finish execution, you can put your code inside the callback function as

```js
client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', async (e) => {

    // if not a document, skip
    if (e.type !== 'Document') return;

    console.log(`adding URL to journey: ${e.documentURL}`)

    // the journey
    journey.push({
      url: e.documentURL,
      type: e.redirectResponse ? e.redirectResponse.status : 'JS Redirection',
      duration_in_ms: 0,
      duration_in_sec: 0,
      loaded_at: dayjs().valueOf()
    });

    await page.goto(goToUrl);
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await browser.close();
  
    console.log('=== JOURNEY ===')
    console.log(journey)

});
```

Comment: Okay, if I remove the `await` from `client.on` and move the other bits into that like your example, I'm not getting anything at all, if I add a `console.log('foo')` just before the `if (e.type)` I don't see the console.log in my terminal, and Puppeteer isn't going to the `await page.goto(goToUrl);`

Comment: This means that `client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent'` is not being called at all.

Comment: `await page.goto(goToUrl);` Starts me on a URL, that URL redirects to another URL and so fourth, moving this outside of `client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent')` works for all of the pages apart from the ones that have a JS `setTimeout` to redirect to another, thus the reason for the Stackoverflow issue, not sure how to resolve this, at a brick wall now.

Comment: put these two lines before `client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent')`
`await page.goto(goToUrl);
    await page.waitForNavigation();`

Comment: Okay, doing that gives me all of the URLs, but out of order. Example, the last page out of a series of pages ends up second in my `journey` array, and the first page I land on appears three times last in the `journey` array